# Update the SQLite Database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, there is a **Picker** which gets the Bank List from Database, and this DB gets the Bank details through an API.

Everything works fine, but now, I want to update the DB, if the new Banks are added in API, I want to add them in the existing database.

I wrote this small code, but the problem is, it first output all the existing records from the database and then print the new records, many times as the total amount of records e.g. (if there are ten records, it will print every record ten times).

**ViewModel.cs**

```
// Load all Banks into a List
var getBanks = await App.Database.GetBankAsync();

// Update the Bank Details where new Banks doesn't exist in the Database
List<Bank> updateBanks = new List<Bank>();

foreach (Banks i in obj.banks)
{
    foreach (var record in getBanks.Where(c => c.Name != i.alias.name))
    {
        updateBanks.Add(new Bank { Name = i.alias.name, Status = "Not Registered" });
    }
}

foreach (var bank in updateBanks)
{
    await App.Database.SaveBankAsync(bank);
}

// Load all Banks into a List
var getBanksUpdated = await App.Database.GetBankAsync();

// Load the Banks whose Status is "Not Registered"
foreach (var record in getBanks.Where(c => c.Status == "Not Registered")
{
    _bankList.Add(record);
}
```

```
public class Alias
{
public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Banks
{
public Alias alias { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public List<Banks> banks { get; set; }
}
```

**Data getting through API**

```
{
    success: true,
    banks: [
        {
        alias: {
        name: "Bank 1",
        Address: "Earth"
        },
        endpoint: {
        uri: "http://127.0.0.1:0000"
        },
        state: "Registered",
        createdAtUtc: "2021-01-19T13:55:12.2318662",
        updatedAtUtc: "2021-01-19T13:55:14.9944042"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Code to get the data from API**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
Uri getDataBanks = new Uri(string.Format("http://127.0.0.1:0000/Banks"));

HttpResponseMessage restponseBanks = await httpClient.GetAsync(getDataBanks);
string contentBanks = await restponseBanks.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contentBanks);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// get the names of all existing banks
List<string> names= obj.banks.Select(u => u.Name).ToList();

// get the names of all banks taken from the API
List<string> names_new= getBanks.Select(u => u.Name).ToList();

foreach (var record in names_new)
{
//check if the bank is exists or not
     if(! names.contains(record)
     {
        updateBanks.Add(new Bank { Name = record.alias.name, Status = "Not Registered" });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of your data, but you you have too foreach loops and you are checking the whole collection in every loop. SO, it's possible, that your condition catches every account on every loop.

Comment: this statement is the one which has to add the new records in existing database`foreach (var record in getBanks.Where(c => c.Name != i.alias.name))` .. but the question is how will u do it? or what's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: no, you check against every alias in every loop... and a!=b a!=c a!=a so, i think thats the problem. And sorry, i have no idea how to achieve, then you have to clearify your question ang give additional and detailed info about your data

Comment: I posted a data format I'm getting through api.. please have a look :)

Comment: okay, im struggeling with your objects, you use `obj` from which I don't know what that is :) I think that is the collection of "not registered" banks. so, before adding that bank you may check, if that bank is alredy part of the `updateBanks` object and only add if there is no entry

Comment: I posted the code above for getting the data from api..